# How can I reference a class from a string?

Tags: python-3.x, class, reference

There are several related questions but I'm not quite seeing how to apply the answers in my situation.

I'm trying to define as a constant whether to use program A or B.

In a Constants module I set a string for A or B:

> DL_PROG = "youtube_dl"  # or, use the better version, yt-dlp

In the module that uses the program:

> import Constants
>
> ...
>
> DL_PROG.YoutubeDL(dlOpts).download(newUrls)

How can I accomplish this properly, cleanly?

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you are trying to access the class name from different module.

You can try to use `importlib` here.

Example:

greeting.py

```py
class Hello:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    
    def print_greetings(self):
        print("Namaste!")
```

main.py

```py
import importlib

greetings_module = importlib.import_module("greetings")

class_name = "Hello"

class_obj = getattr(
        greetings_module,
        class_name,
    )

class_obj().print_greetings()
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you kindly for the reply. However, wouldn't that require a separate file just for this particular constant? My Constants.py file contains many other (more standard) constant definitions, DL_PROG is just one of them.  I'm just not seeing how to apply your example in a clean way.

Comment: Then probably I didn't get your question properly.. Can you give some more context?